# How to convert Redis date in R

Tags: r, parsing, date, redis

I am trying to convert this kind of date: "Tue Aug 12 2014 19:47:50 GMT+0000 (UTC)"

```
parseRedisDate <- function(date) {
    x <- gsub(" GMT\\+0000 \\(UTC\\)", "", date)
    as.Date(x, format="%a %b %d %Y %T")
}
date <- "Tue Aug 12 2014 19:47:50 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
parseRedisDate(date)
```

Not working...

Comment: What isn't working?  Seems to be working over here.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what you want as a result?

Comment: "Not working" is not a valid description of a problem. What did you get and what did you expect to get?

Comment: Your code is working fine. If it is not, try (like in @nicolas answer) `Sys.setlocale(category="LC_TIME","C")`. Now we can close this

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `date` as an object name, since that's a function in base R. But otherwise your function seems to work. The core bit of it:

```
x <- as.Date(gsub(" GMT\\+0000 \\(UTC\\)", "",
                  'Tue Aug 12 2014 19:47:50 GMT+0000 (UTC)'),
             format="%a %b %d %Y %T")
x
```

returns:

```
[1] "2014-08-12"
```

and

```
class(x)
```

returns:

```
[1] "Date"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the full datetime, you can easily coerce that string to an object of class `POSIXct`:

```
    x<-"Tue Aug 12 2014 19:47:50 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
    as.POSIXct(x,format="%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

This may fail if your locale isn't set to understand the English month and day names. You can set the locale through:

```
    Sys.setlocale(category="LC_TIME","C")
```

and the above commands will work. If you just need the date (without the time), you can coerce the `POSIXct` to `Date`:

```
    as.Date(as.POSIXct(x,format="%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S"))
```