# R convert string in date format

Tags: r, date, format

I'm having some problems converting string vectors into date format. I have found a lot of information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25897612/how-to-convert-redis-date-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834169/how-to-convert-a-string-like-sat-mar-17-112757-0000-2012-into-date-in-r) but they haven't worked in my case (R 3.2.3).

```
> strptime("Fri Feb 05 14:10:10 +0000 2016",
            format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y", tz="GMT")
[1] NA
```

Comment: have you checked the manual, or any [tutorials](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/STAT/r/faq/string_dates.htm) on the topic?

Comment: works fine by me..

Comment: Yes - works fine for me too (version 3.2.5). Have you tried upgrading?

Comment: Did you try `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")` ?

Comment: Indeed check your Locale; for instance if French, "Fri" is not a valid day name ("Ven" for Vendredi)

Comment: Thank you  @DavidArenburg and EricLecoutre ! it was a problem with my locals variables in france!